# Migration C++ to C# (CALLBACK)

Tags: c#, c++, callback, migration

I am currently doing a migration of c++ to c # and I presented the following problem which I have not the faintest idea as can be done within c #

```
typedef void (CALLBACK *funtion1)(int a , int b);

void SetCallBackFuntion(funtion1 pfn);


void something(){

obj->SetCallBackFuntion(&funtion1);

}
```

Comment: You want to **call** this code from C#?

Comment: yes, I want to know how to write in c #

Comment: No, there is a difference. Do you have a C++ library with code like this that you want to **call** from C#. OR, do you want to **write equivalent C# code** ??

Comment: I have a library in c # and c ++ as well as documentation of the libraries but only in c ++ and the project I'm doing it in c # I have drawn on ideas of the codes with examples and documentation of the library in c ++ but there are parts like this that not as would be the equivalent. The help I need is to know how to write the equivalent but in c #

Comment: Far as I can tell, he's trying to write the equivalent in C#, not call into an existing C++ library. At least that's the impression I get from his use of "migration," though the question could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve the equivilant behaviour in C# depending on how you want it to work and what version of .NET you're targeting. The easiest method is to use an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).

To implement this using C# standards it should first be noted that it fits better as a property rather than a method. Also, because the callback doesn't return a value it's referred to as a method, not a function. So the code above would look something like this:

```
public Action<int,int> CallBack { set; }

public void Something()
{
    obj.CallBack = function1;
}
```

And the code to call the callback would do something like this:

```
if(CallBack != null)
    CallBack(1, 2);
```

Another approach is to use a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is just a slightly more verbose way of describing an Action and compatible with older versions of .NET. It also translates more closely with the C++ code. Note: Although this would technically work (assuming you implemented the rest correctly) it's not normally regarded as good practice. I just wanted to show you a quick and dirty way.

```
public delegate void CallBack(int x, int y);

private void SetCallBackFuntion(CallBack pfn)
{
}

private void Something()
{
    obj.SetCallBackFuntion(funtion1);
}
```

A third approach is to use interfaces. You could describe an interface with your method signature like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void CallBack(int x, int y);
}
```

and then you could have a property on your class similar to the Action but using the interface instead.

```
public IMyInterface CallBackObject { set; }

public void Something()
{
    obj.CallBackObject = someObject;
}

if(CallBackObject != null)
    CallBackObject.CallBack(1, 2);
```

The final approach that comes to mind is to use event handlers, but since they are more useful when you have multiple subscribers to your callback, I won't cover them here.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much friend for taking the time to help me, I'm new to programming in c #. Regards from Venezuela.

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply written in C# with **delegates**